# Error: Use CoffeeScript.register() or require the coffee-script/register module to require .iced.md files

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

my `app.js` is:

```
require("iced-coffee-script");
require("./serverOneNode.iced");
```

when I run it:

```
node app.js
```

got error:

```
/projectPath/node_modules/iced-coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:200
          throw new Error("Use CoffeeScript.register() or require the coffee-s
                ^
Error: Use CoffeeScript.register() or require the coffee-script/register module to require .iced.md files.
  at Object._base.(anonymous function) [as .iced] (/projectPath/node_modules/iced-coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:200:17)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/projectPath/app.js:2:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:902:3
```

That began to happen after I updated `iced-coffee-script` and `coffee-script`.

Answer (score 1):

I added line `require('iced-coffee-script/register');` to file `app.js` before requiring `serverOneNode.iced` and problem was solved successfully.